# How to return DataSet in EntityFramework 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have this method that returns obj `Data`, but instead of that I need to return `DataSet`

```
public static Data GetData(int id)
{
    var result = new Data();
    using (var context = new MyContext(false, false)) 
    {
        var query = context.Data.Include("MyTable1").Include("MyTable2").Include("MyTable3").Where(o => o.Id == id);
        result = query.OrderBy(onc => onc.Data).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'm new to Entity Framework, any example how can I return DataSet instead of object.

Comment: Use LINQToDataTable : https://forums.asp.net/t/1559861.aspx?How+to+convert+entity+collections+to+a+dataset+&force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your `Data` object into Dataset and return it.
Here is example,

```
 private DataSet ConvertToDataSet(Data yourObject) 
 {
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     //build the columns by your fields
     dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
     dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

     DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
     row["Id"] = yourObject.Id;
     row["Name"] = yourObject.Name
     dt.Rows.Add(row);

     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     ds.Tables.Add(dt);
     return ds;
  }



  public static DataSet GetData(int id)
  {
    var result = new Data();
    using (var context = new MyContext(false, false)) 
    {
        var query = context.Data.Include("MyTable1").Include("MyTable2").Include("MyTable3").Where(o => o.Id == id);
        result = query.OrderBy(onc => onc.Data).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return ConvertToDataSet(result);
  }
```